# how to exit from multiple foreach

Tags: php

i have a multiple foreach (loop) as below:

```
foreach($Arr1 as $k1=>$v1){ //Loop 1

    foreach($v1 as $k2=>$v2) { //Loop 2

        foreach($v2 as $k3=>$v3) { //Loop 3

            if($v3==0){ echo "Yes! Found Zero & Exit the Entire Loop"; break; }

        }

    }
}
```

in my code, i did put in the "break" but i only exit //Loop3 and continue from //Loop 2 again, so is that a wait to exit the entire loop?
 if i put exit, yes it stop but my entire page stop also.

Comment: http://www.php.net/break

Comment: a single "break" will not exit the entire loop!!!!

Answer (score 8):

Use `break 3;` to break out of all of your loops.

<sub>[[`break`](http://www.php.net/break) actually takes a "parameter" which tells it how many loops to break out of]</sub>

`break;` (with no number) is the same as `break 1;` (<strike>and `break 0;`</strike> `break 0;` no longer works).

Comment: @user1493339: `continue;` also accepts a "parameter" :-)

Answer (score 4):

[According to the docs](http://www.php.net/break) you can specify a number of loops to break out of like this:

```
break 3;
```

Comment: thanks Matt Cain, now only i know break can come with parameter

Answer (score 4):

I'd probably re-write this using a function

```
function multiLoop($array)

    foreach ($array as $k1 => $v1) {

      foreach ($v1 as $k2 => $v2) {

        foreach ($v2 as $k3 => $v3) {

          if ($v3 == "0") {
            return $k3;
          }

      }
    }
  }
}

echo "0 found at " . multiLoop($input)
```

Answer (score -1):

```
break;
```

That will take you out of any loop.